# Should I check and free pointer in VLA class' assign operator (operator=)

Tags: c++, assignment-operator

So let's say we have a simple variable-length array class like following:

```
struct VLA {
    double* d=nullptr;
    int dim;
}
```

What makes me wonder is, within `operator=`, should I check (and perhaps free/delete if not `nullptr`) `d` before malloc/new an new array for it? As assignment is different from copy constructor where it might originally also carried an array.

---

Like following example:

```cpp
operator=(VLA &other) {
    double *tmp=new double[dim];
    memcpy(tmp, other.d, sizeof(double)*other.dim);
    delete[]d;
    d=tmp;
    dim=other.dim;
}
```

Is the `delete[]d` required?

Comment: VLA refers to some specific construct available in C. Also the free and malloc tags are not that relevant here

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three. Well, not directly i suppose, but you need more than that `delete` to have a class that is not horribly broken

Comment: maybe you already have more of the special member functions. You should include them in the question, because they are closely related.

Comment: When reassigning objects it is your duty to free old memory to prevent a leak. `delete` will safely handle null pointers. You do not need to assert that `new` is not null, it will throw an exception if it cannot allocate. If you want `new` to return null when allocation fails use `new(::std::nothrow) double[]`.

Comment: for example without a proper constructor the `delete` might be called with `d` uninitialized.

Comment: @Andrew.Wolphoe *should I check (and perhaps free/delete if not nullptr) d before malloc/new an new array for it?* -- If you have a proper copy constructor and destructor, then there is no need to do any checking.  `VLA temp(other); std::swap(temp.d, d), std::swap(temp.dim, dim);` -- Those three lines alone do all the work you're doing now.

Comment: C++ already has a "VLA" called `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

> within `operator=`, should I check (and perhaps free/delete if not `nullptr`) `d` before malloc/new an new array for it?
>
> Is the `delete[]d` required?

If you are going to allocate a new array with `new[]`, then yes, you need to free the the old array with `delete[]`, otherwise it will be leaked.  Whether you do that before or after allocating the new array is up to you, but I would do it after, in case allocating the new array fails.

Note that you can optimize the code you have shown a little, by skipping the `new[]`/`delete[]` if the new `dim` is the same value as the old `dim`, and by using the [copy-swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/) when you do allocate a new array:

```cpp
VLA(const VLA &other) {
    d = new double[other.dim];
    memcpy(d, other.d, sizeof(double) * other.dim);
    dim = other.dim;
}

VLA& operator=(const VLA &other) {
    if (this != &other) {
        if (dim == other.dim) {
            memcpy(d, other.d, sizeof(double) * other.dim);
        else {
            VLA temp(other);
            std::swap(d, temp.d);
            std::swap(dim, temp.dim);
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Though, you really should should be using `std::vector` instead of `new[]`/`delete[]` manually at all.  Let `std::vector` handle the array for you:

```cpp
#include <vector>

struct VLA {
    std::vector<double> d;
    int dim() const { return d.size(); }

    // compiler-generated copy constructor will "do the right thing"...
    // compiler-generated operator=() will "do the right thing"...
};
```